# Hide drop down list on conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, show-hide

I am simply trying to hide a select list/drop down list on an html page. I am not trying to hide the options in the select list, just the select list overall. I am having the hardest time for some unknown reason. I cannot figure out how to do this.

HTML

```
<HTML>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
       var myVal = 10;
       if (myVal = 10) {
          document.getElementById("contracts").style.visibility="hidden";
       }
    </script
</head>
<body>  
<select id="contracts" name ="contracts" style="width:99%;height:50px"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

As simpel as can be, yet I cannot figure out how to hide the select list. It's still present on my page. This example is actually hiding the values in my select list but not the overall select list. Does anyone know how to accomplish this? I am out of ideas. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('contracts').style.display = 'none';
```

The above should do
You man consider using jQuery though. Makes your life simple

```
$('#contracts').hide();
```

That's all

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

try and move the script to the bottom of the page. It's executing before the element is loaded. You could also put it in the "onload" function

```
window.onload = function(){

       var myVal = 10;
       if (myVal = 10) {
          document.getElementById("contracts").style.visibility="hidden";
       }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of visibility, you should be looking at display property. Check the snippet below.

```html
<HTML>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>  
<select id="contracts" name ="contracts" style="width:99%;height:50px"></select>
</body>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">    
    var myVal = 10;
    if (myVal = 10) {
      document.getElementById("contracts").style.display="none";
    }
  </script
    
</html>
```